# Grid View Footer doesn't show even though the footer template exists

Tags: asp.net

I have a Grid View. The Data displays correctly. However the footer doesn't show. Can anyone tell me what is wrong ?

Below is the code:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdJLLAlloc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="400px"
    ShowFooter="True" CellPadding="4" SkinID="OrigBkrAlloc">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Professional" HeaderText="Professional" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Market" HeaderText="Market" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessLine" HeaderText="Business Line" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PSBusinessUnit" HeaderText="Business Unit" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="%">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" Width="170px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJLLAllocPercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Percentage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJLLAllocTotalPer" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" Width="170px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJLLAllocAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJLLAllocTotalAmt" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Private Sub LoadJllAllocGrid()
            Dim dsJLLCommAlloc As New DataSet("JLLCommissionAlloc")
            Try
                If m_DealId > 0 Then
                    dsJLLCommAlloc = oComm.GetCapForceJLLCommissionAlloc(m_DealId)
                    grdJLLAlloc.DataSource = dsJLLCommAlloc
                    grdJLLAlloc.DataBind()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, Common.EXCEPTION_POLICY)
            End Try
        End Sub

Private Sub grdJLLAlloc_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdJLLAlloc.RowDataBound
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
                Dim lblTotalAmt As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblJLLAllocTotalAmt"), Label)
                lblTotalAmt.Text = "100,000$"
            End If

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to bind the `grdJLLAlloc_RowDataBound` method to the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdJLLAlloc" OnRowDataBound="grdJLLAlloc_RowDataBound"
```

Comment: I added that and still the same result. Not sure what is happening.